# What's the final word on JavaScript-initiated redirects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, href

**Consider**:

```
<a href="some-page.html">Go</a>
```

**Vs**:

```
<script>

$(function(){

  $('a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var self = $(this);

    window.setTimeout(function(){

      window.location = self.attr('href');

    }, 1000);
  });
});

</script>

<a href="some-page.html">Go</a>
```

Obviously the intention of the second one is to delay the redirect (specifically to allow an animation to finish). This also falls nicely back for browsers with disabled JavaScript.

But are there any specific scenarios where a JavaScript link will get rejected by a browser preventing pop-ups? If so, which are the problem browsers? Are there steps you can take to prevent browser suspicion when you're simply navigating around your own site?

A definitive answer or a link to an answer containing any knowledge regarding how browsers handle/reject page redirects would be great.

Comment: *"But are there any specific scenarios where a JavaScript link will get rejected by a browser preventing pop-ups"* no because it isn't a popup. However, this will break default functionality of links in that you can't middle click it to open in a new tab, I find that to be **VERY** annoying. Definitely not worth doing just for an animation. This is one of the few cases where i would suggest using a synchronous ajax call rather than an asynchronous one that does a window.location on success.

Comment: @KevinB: Heh.  I never realized that middle-clicking a link did something.  I always just right-clicked and picked "Open in new tab".  That's pretty spiffy.  Although one could make the JS so that only the primary (left) button triggered the delay/etc.

Answer (score 0):

> But are there any specific scenarios where a JavaScript link will get
>   rejected by a browser preventing pop-ups?

Your code doesn't creates a pop-up window, but only change what the user see:

```
window.location = self.attr('href');
```

This code do:

```
var newWin = window.open('..');
```

Read more about it: [window.open method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

Comment: Ok. Although I agree not being able to open in a new window, this specific site prioritises a certain experience over the frustration of web-developers who like to dart around the web opening new windows (I am also one of those developers). Could you perhaps elaborate on a possible work-around such that my jQuery embellishment detects the users intention of trying to open a new window? I suspect this isn't possible but figured it would be worth asking...

Comment: What do you want to achieve in your page?

Comment: Ideally, the finishing of an animation, followed by a `window.location` change, unless the user attempts to open in a new window, in which case sod the animation and go open the link...